# como capturar aquilo que é impresso na consola por meio de um comando para dentro de um vetor em linguagem C

Tags: c

Quando eu faço algum comando na consola de linux, por exemplo `man fprintf`,
é impresso na tela uma serie de informação.

Eu preciso de recolher essa informação que é impressa na tela mas no lugar de ser impressa na tela ser encaminhada para um vetor e posteriormente para um ficheiro.

Qual é a forma que eu tenho de capturar aquilo que é escrito na tela e encaminhar isso para um vetor que existe no corpo do código?

Comment: O `man fprintf` básico tem muitos caracteres de controle no output. Podes filtrar esses caracteres com o programa `col`: `man fprintf | col -b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça o seguinte, não testei, mas a solução que me veio a cabeça foi.

Partimos do principio que o comando:

```
man fprintf > saida.txt
```

Salva saída do terminal em um arquivo de texto em algum lugar do pc.

Mas como executar esse comando dentro do seu programa?
Para isso existe uma função chamada `system`. Logo

```
system("man fprintf > saida.txt");
```

o próximo passo é só usar funções de c que fazem a leitura desse arquivo.
Ai você trata da forma que achar melhor.

Comment: Valgrind é utilizado para detetar memory leaks. O que faz output do printado para o ficheiro é o `>`

Comment: Obrigado pela correção @krystalgamer.

Comment: system("man fprintf > saida.txt");
era exatamente o que eu precisava, muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Em **sistemas POSIX** podes fazer o que pretendes com [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html).

*Possivelmente existem outras maneiras específicas para sistemas operativos especificos (Windows, Android, iOS, MINIX, NeXTSTEP, ...)*

Exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char info[1000000]; // 1 Mbytes deve chegar :-)
    size_t infolen = 0;
    char linha[1000];
    size_t linhalen;
    char comando[] = "man fprintf";
    FILE *processo;

    processo = popen(comando, "r");
    if (!processo) {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(linha, sizeof linha, processo)) {
        linhalen = strlen(linha);
        if (infolen + linhalen >= sizeof info) {
            fprintf(stderr, "O output tem muitas linhas.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(info + infolen, linha);
        infolen += linhalen;
    }
    pclose(processo);

    // usa info, por exemplo imprime os 6 primeiros caracteres
    printf("%.6s", info);

    return 0;
}
```